# JSONObject from string on Android

Tags: android, json, getjson

l get string with answer from server. l want to do it JSONObject.

l do

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

in json has

> "{"sentences":[{"trans":"R\u0455R\u0491ReR\u0405","orig":"�\u0455�\u0491��\u0405","translit":"","src_translit":"R\u1E91Rg\u0300RoR\u1E90"}],"src":"ru","server_time":1}"

but jsonObj has

> "{"sentences":[{"src_translit":"RẑRg̀RoRẐ","orig":"�ѕ�ґ��Ѕ","trans":"RѕRґReRЅ","translit":""}],"server_time":1,"src":"ru"}"

so how l can get value from "trans":"RѕRґReRЅ"?

PS RѕRґReRЅ it's "own" in normal charset

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
  JSONArray  sentences = jsonObj.getJSONArray("sentences");
  for(int i=0;i<sentences.length();i++){
    JSONObject number = sentences.getJSONObject(i);
    String transValue = number.getString("trans");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the jsonObj you just have to do:

```
  try {
// Getting Array of Sentences
sentences = json.getJSONArray("sentences");

// looping through All Contacts
for(int i = 0; i < sentences.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = sentences.getJSONObject(i);

    // get the value from trans
    String trans = c.getString("trans");       
  //now you should save this string in an array 

}
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: but l have trans in "RѕRґReRЅ", but must have "own"

Comment: Where are you getting your json? What is your country charset?
If you need to convert to, let's say, utf-8 you have to:
    `URLEncoder.encode(json_string, "UTF-8");`

Comment: I have error:" Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value %7B%22sentences%22%3A%5B%7B%22trans%22%3A%22R%5Cu0455R%5Cu0491ReR%5Cu0405%22%2C%22orig%22%3A%22%EF%BF%BD%5Cu0455%EF%BF%BD%5Cu0491%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%5Cu0405%22%2C%22translit%22%3A%22%22%2C%22src_translit%22%3A%22R%5Cu1E91Rg%5Cu0300RoR%5Cu1E90%22%7D%5D%2C%22src%22%3A%22ru%22%2C%22server_time%22%3A24%7D%0A of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Comment: before encoding json string is " {"sentences":[{"trans":"R\u0455R\u0491ReR\u0405","orig":"�\u0455�\u0491��\u0405","translit":"","src_translit":"R\u1E91Rg\u0300RoR\u1E90"}],"src":"ru","server_time":24}"

Comment: Before doing anything you have to remove the quotes (" "). Secondly you will have to encode the charset that you have received to the charset appropriated. Take a look at this: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.pt/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove single quote form starting and from ending of your JSON string (**json**), by this your JSON will be a valid json for this you have to do like :

```
json= json.substring(1, json.length()-1);
```

After that you do like this :

```
JSONObject oJsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray  oJsonArray   = oJsonObject.getJSONArray("sentences");

for(int i=0; i<oJsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject oJsonObject1 = oJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String transValue = oJsonObject1 .getString("trans");
}
```

Comment: on JSONObject oJsonObject = new JSONObject(json); I have error: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value sentences of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: "{"sentences":[{"trans":"R\u0455R\u0491ReR\u0405","orig":"�\u0455�\u0491��\u0405","translit":"","src_translit":"R\u1E91Rg\u0300RoR\u1E90"}],"src":"ru","server_time":1}"

Comment: Again your json showing double quote at starting of the string as well at last, as I mentioned you have to remove those before parse you can parse only this :    {"sentences":[{"trans":"R\u0455R\u0491ReR\u0405","orig":"�\u0455�\u0491��\u0405‌​","translit":"","src_translit":"R\u1E91Rg\u0300RoR\u1E90"}],"src":"ru","server_ti‌​me":1}